# 9 trees in 7 rows with 3 trees in each row

Tags: mathematics, geometry

The following puzzle is a variant of a puzzle published in the May 8, 1926 issue of **THE WINNIPEG TRIBUNE MAGAZINE**:

In the picture below there are nine trees arranged in two rows with five trees in each row.  The puzzle is to reposition four of the trees leaving the other trees untouched so that you wind up with exactly seven rows with three trees in each row.  Rows can be horizontal, vertical or slanted at any angle.

[image: 9 trees arranged in the shape of a PLUS sign (5 trees horizontal and 5 trees vertical)]

Comment: I might be the odd one out, but I would argue this puzzle could be improved by replacing the word 'row' with 'line'. Calling two perpendicular lines rows seems weird/confusing to me?

Comment: @DavidMulder I am sorry that the word "row" was confusing.  However, "row" is the standard word for this type of puzzle (I checked a number of sources).  I will update my question.

Comment: @DavidMulder A row of trees going north-south is as much as a row of trees going east-west.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Taking each row on its own I would wholeheartedly agree, but when you have e.g. a 2x2 grid I would say that that grid has two rows and two columns, not four rows and two columns. And I believe the same would apply to any set/group/collection of rows.

Comment: You should clarify exactly 7 rows. My first thought was to arrange in a 3x3 grid.

Comment: @qwr Thanks for your recommendation.  I have added the word ‘exactly’ to the text of my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A different solution is possible:

> [image]

Comment: Nice symmetrical solution!  Nicely explained too!

Comment: Just put them into a 3x3 box at first, then did stuff to get rid of one row.

Answer (score 13):

How about the following arrangement?

> [image: solution]

> Made from moving the four trees farthest from the center.

Comment: Yes, that works.  Can you find a symmetrical solution?

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Ah, yes, simply shift the top row over by one. I'll edit my answer

Comment: This new solution makes 8 rows (not just 7), with the long diagonal from bottom left to top right... (This is also achieved by just positioning the 9 trees in a 3x3 square grid.)

Comment: if you move the left tree in the first row of your original answer down three rows then you get a symmetric solution with 7 rows (and not more)

Comment: My bad, I'll revert my edit.

Answer (score 11):

I'm quite happy with the result, and had fun thinking about it

> [image]

Comment: I like your symmetrical solution.  You explained your answer well.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't quite follow the rules

> but why move 4 trees when it can be done in 3? 
>  [image]

Answer (score 8):

Yet another answer.  Who said all the trees must be used?

> [image]

Comment: Cool!  Thinking outside of the box!

Comment: I like the way you show the original positions of the moved trees here.  That's a really good visual representation.

Answer (score 6):

I can actually make 9 rows with 3 trees in each row by just moving 4 trees. I will keep the top and bottom tree and the three center ones in place and move the other 4 to build the following pattern (F for fixed trees and M for the ones I moved).

> [image: solution]

Sorry for not actually having nice trees in my picture. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Ideally I am looking for a solution with exactly 7 rows.

Comment: Move the top right M further out along its line and you eliminate 2 rows to leave 7.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would be allowed, because this solution involves

> trees being not exactly grid aligned, and also one row having way different spaceing between trees. Though, I did try to keep the distance within each row the same, because this would be really easy if any adjacent trees in a row can be any distance apart.

> [image]

Comment: That looks perfectly good to me, except you forgot to draw one line.

Comment: @FlorianF That looks like seven lines to me though.. Three horizontal, one vertical, two negative diagonals, and one positive diagonal.

Comment: Oops, it seems I cannot count.  I saw an additional row from the top left to the bottom right tree, but I didn't see that you moved the bottom right tree to avoid that.  So no objection.  Grid alignment was not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Found this one:

> [image: Answer]

Here's how I did it.

> [image: Explanations]

Comment: Nice symmetrical solution.